# Remove branches in Mercurial but keep changes?

Tags: mercurial

I just found out that we're not supposed to create named branches in our local Mercurial repos, because they get carried along and pushed to the upstream repo, where they live forever.

Unfortunately, I already have multiple feature branches in my local repo, which I was all set to merge to `default` and push up to the main repo. So, what I need to do is keep the work in these branches (somehow) but remove the named branches.

Is there a way to do this, short of a lot of horrible manual revert/cut/paste?

Comment: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TortoiseHg:

*(Ensure rebase extension is enabled in File -> Settings -> Extensions)*

1. Update to parent of the first change set of the named branch.
2. Right click on the first change set of the nambed branch and click rebase.
3. Ensure "Keep orignal branch names (--keepbranches)" is **NOT** checked.
4. Ensure "Rebase entire source branch (-b/--base)" **is** checked.
5. Click rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the `hg convert` command (a standard extension) and [the branchmap option](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap).

For a private repository or at least one with changesets which have not been published this would work fine, even though like a rebase it would modify history.

An advantage as opposed to using rebase is that it could be used to deal with multiple branches (named or unnamed) all at once. That might be quicker / easier if there was a lot of things to move around.

A secondary plus is that since `convert` will create a NEW repository there is no risk to the original if something doesn't work as expected. (Of course when using rebase you could make a backup first which I think is a reasonable precaution.)

Comment: how can you remove branch by using *hg convert*? I'm not able to find it, not even with `--branchmap` option

Comment: Hi @superjos, iirc branches will only be copied by convert of they are specifically included in the branch map. So you can remove them by omitting them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Let's see if I got what you're suggesting: - when I don't apply any branchmap, all branches are copied over; - when I apply a branchmap file, only branches listed in that file will be included, with the renaming I specify. Is that right?

Comment: @superjos yes I think so