# TortoiseHG Workbench - Delete Dropdown list with branch versions

Tags: tortoisehg

If I create a new branch in TortoiseHG then I get a new window to Enter the new Version. This list always starts from the lowest number so its very annoying! I always have to scroll down or Enter a new Version manually into the DropDown list. Can I change this behaviour or delete the list?

I dont know how to change this, simply press the DEL key doesnt work ;)

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add the picture.

Comment: ok that sounds correct. So when I could delete the very old branches, these entries will disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Those entries in the dropdown are names of other existing branches. I guess they are there to provide you with a hint or starting point.

*Maybe* if you close those branches Tortoise will hide them from the list (but I'm not sure about that): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681228/3195477

Presumably if you "deleted" those older branches from Mercurial then they would no longer appear. Technically you can't delete branches however - though you can work around that using `hg convert` to create a new independent repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47421857/3195477

However I'm not sure the last suggestion is worth the time and effort and other complications for such a small issue.